# Windows server 2008 only uses half my RAM

Tags: windows, memory, windows-server-2008-r2, memory-usage

I have just bought the HP ProLiant G7 N54L 2.2GHz MicroServer, I have upgraded the RAM to 8gb (2x4GB),

(http://www.ebuyer.com/430446-proliant-microserver-turion-2-2-2gb-250gb-nhpl-sata-lff-in-704941-421)

I am running Windows server 2008 R2 x64, The RAM has been found by the OS but it is only using 3.75GB.

I am sure it is just me being stupid but I can't find anything with the BIOS or the OS to change.

I have had a look around online and still no luck.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: well, its a 64 bit processor and OS, so thats not the issue.  Does BIOS recognize all 8GB?  Are you sure the RAM is seated properly?

Comment: The Bios only see's 4GB, but the OS see both Sticks says 8GB installed but still only uses 3.75GB

Comment: Try updating the BIOS itself

Comment: updated Ram and still no change

Comment: The Ram Stick was Damaged and I have replaced it. 
looks to be working now!

Thanks for all the help.